# Potential security issue with Facebook login?

Tags: facebook, security

I am currently implementing Facebook Login on my website for the first time and I have some doubts on how secure this is.

I already have a database with users and for each one of them, I store an email address, so I really need to check whether an email address I get from Facebook is already present in my database or not, otherwise I would have some problems with duplicate users. If a user is already present, I simply merge data from Facebook into the existing account on my website and I connect the user. Otherwise, I create an account for him.

But here is the thing:

1. Alice connects on my website using email address *alice@users.com* but **Alice is not registered on Facebook** with that email address
2. Bob registers on Facebook using Alice's email address *alice@users.com* and verify the account using an SMS received on any phone number (I checked and this is possible, an account can be verified without clicking on the link received by email). I agree that Alice would be notified on her email address but still, this is possible.
3. Bob triggers login on my website using facebook connect, while being connected on Facebook using Alice's email address.
4. Bob's Facebook account is active and verified, and I have to assume he already has an account on my website as *alice@users.com* is already in my database, so I connect him instead of Alice and he can use my website on Alice's account.

=> I tried this scenario on several websites and I could connect on someone else's account (a fake Facebook account that I created ;) ), as long as I knew the email address.

Does anyone have an idea on how to prevent these situations?

Comment: In the facebook API, the user has a "verified" field. Is it only true if the user has verified the email, or also if he verified the phone number ?

Comment: According to Facebook documentation, a user is considered as "verified" if he "registers for mobile", "confirms her account via SMS" or "enters a valid credit card" so I guess this field won't help unfortunately

Comment: Just a thought: It's possible to change your facebook email address. Say I registered as alice@users.com, then changed my email on facebook to bob@users.com. Now I make another account there as alice@users.com. If you have a registration from alice@facebook.com, which account is it from? That depends!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is true that Facebook doesn't need to confirm email and then acts as an openid-style provider, then this is shocking! But i guess the answer is already in your question - don't link/merge accounts. Or at least, don't do so from a facebook login attempt without first confirming the email yourself.

You can't change what friendface does, so you need to treat the email address provided by facebook connect as untrusted data. If a Facebook-connect login attempt is made with an email that already has a native account on your site, then send them an email confirmation code yourself - and do what facebook failed to do.

Another option is once a user is logged in to a native account, you could allow them to link the facebook account from there, should they wish to. This also allows you to support facebook login for users that have a different email address registered on the two sites.

Comment: Allowing them to link the accounts with an email verification would pretty much ensure you know who the user is.

Comment: @Lix ermm... yeah. damn good point - answer updated :-)

Comment: Good point, I think this should be the most secure solution. However, people are getting more and more used to the fact that once you click on the Facebook connect button, you are logged in straight away on the website. But I think an email validation from my website seems to be necessary!

Comment: Yacine, remember that in a huge majority of cases people will "log straight in"; you only need this confirmation when merging accounts - and i doubt you'll get all that many users that create a native account and then log in with friendface. The only complication is that you want to merge account data, so in the few cases that this comes up, you go the extra step to confirm the email before giving over a  user's secrets to what is essentially a different account.

Comment: @YacineS. - As I pointed out if two people used the same email  one your system should allow two accounts to be created one where a Facebook account was used and the other was a classic account created before Facebook Connect supported was added to your website.  In your examples Alice@ABC.com and the Facebook account registered to Alice@CBA.com could be linked to the same account.

Comment: I agree with you Cheekysoft, if someone triggers facebook connect on my website and the email address is already in use, I should perform a specific action like "merge your facebook account to your existing account with an email confirmation". Sounds very good to me, thanks for your quick help!

Comment: @Ramhound I would really prefer merging the accounts as far as I'm concerned because I think users would expect this behaviour

Comment: @YacineS. - I don't think you understand what I am trying to suggest.  If somebody wants to link their Facebook account allow them through your user mangement website otherwise treat ANY facebook account registered to the email address as a seperate account.  It avoids ALL 4 issues you described.

Answer (score 1):

this i think it's not a facebook bug/flow. The problem is in the algorithm that is used by the sites that accept facebook login.

Facebook logins should not be accepted if that email address is already registered in the site. It may called "facebook login" but not forget that it really is a new account of the site database and should be treated like one.

In conclusion, if the site uses e-mail addresses as unique identification, should not accept facebook logins with the same e-mail address.